# Explainer badge - the 12 hours should be based on when the edit was made, not approved?

Tags: feature-request, badges, edit-and-answer-badges

I've been finding that even when I edit a question, and then immediately write an answer, the time for edits to be approved can often exceed 12 hours. I'm thinking that's why these often don't count towards the Explainer badge. Another exacerbating factor is that my edit queue can get full and remain so for a couple of days until cleared by someone; this edit queue issue is mostly only with Stack Overflow, whereas the Explainer badge issue of exceeding 12 hours happens on various Stack Exchange sites as well.

Could the timing of the 12 hours be made with reference to when the edit was made, rather than (as it appears to be currently) with reference to when it is approved?

Comment: Oops. I guess it has been a problem for years, and nothing has been done to change it. Shouldn't be too complicated of a change for developers to make, to track the time the edit was actually made/suggested.